# method availability in golang

Tags: go, types

I am currently learning what the `type` keyword is in golang.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type celsius float64

func (c celsius) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%.2f C !!!", c)
}

func main() {
    var celVar celsius = 2
    fmt.Println(celVar)   // prints "2.00 C !!!" // LINE 2
    
    c := celsius(10).String() // LINE 4
    fmt.Println(c) // prints "10.00 C !!!" 

    t := celsius(10)  // LINE 7
    fmt.Println(t) // prints "10.00 C !!!" 
}
```

1. On LINE 2, why does `fmt.Println(celVar)` print "2.00 C !!!"?
   Since `celVar` is not explicitly using `String()` method, I expected the printed value to be "2.00"
2. Why do LINE 4 and LINE 7 result in the same value?
   Again, LINE 7 did not explicitly use the `String()` method, so I expected it should not be invoking that method.
3. Also, when `initializing` type in golang, is it customary to use parentheses like `celsius(10)`?

Comment: Always read the full documentatio of functions you use. All this is unrelated to the type keyword.

Comment: *"I am currently learning what the type keyword is in golang."* Do note that 1., 2., and 3. have nothing to do with the `type` *keyword*.

Comment: Thanks, but just letting you know the document itself may be difficult for beginners depending on the section. Yes indeed, I now understand my question was not directly related to `type`, so I have edited the title of the question. @Volker @mkopriva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing) for the `fmt` package:

> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be
>    formatted as required by the verb (if any).

Effectively, it checks whether something implements the [fmt.Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface.

This rule applies to your first and third print statements. The format package first checks whether your type has a `func String() string` method on it. Since it does, it uses this rather than the float64 value.

If you want to override this default, you can pass a float verb to `fmt`:

```golang
fmt.Printf("%f\n",celVar)
>> 2.000000
```

For your final question: `celsius(10)` is a [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) and is fairly standard.